# JSON data populating only with first letter in DataTable

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, datatables, yaml

I am using the Rasa X HTTP API to parse a yaml file and convert to a JSON object. I want to take this JSON object and then send it to my datatable to populate the rows. The problem is when I populate the datatable when calling the function in my datatable javascript, the JSON returns like this:

[image]

The API according to the docs here turns the payload into JSON format: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/pages/http-api#operation/getDomain

Here is my code for the HTTP API:

```
export function getDomain(token) { //used to get auth token which is recreated each instance
    var data = ""
    //console.log(token);
    var header_data = { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }
    //console.log(header_data);
    var sendData = {} //data to send. Check Rasa x API doc
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5002/api/domain',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        headers: header_data,
        success: function (resp) {
            //put name of json value you want to read after 'resp.'
            //console.log(data);
            
            var jsonDomain = yaml.parse(resp);
            data = jsonDomain.entities;
            console.log(typeof (data));
            return data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Error ${error}');
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

This function above parses the yaml file to get the data

```
export function getAuth() { //used to get auth token which is recreated each instance
    var data = "";
    var sendData = { "username": "me", "password":"huiwehfuiwfa" } //password changes each instance, there is a way to create a constant one too
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost:5002/api/auth',
        //projects/default/intents',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false, //depracted but needs to be included to have it work
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        dataType: 'json',  
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp.access_token; //put name of json value you want to read after 'resp.'
            return data;

            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Error ${error}');
        }
    });
return data;
}
```

This function gives authorization to use the API, gets the datatype as JSON, and stringifys it.
The console log for this shows as an object:

```
(3) ["plant", "water", "temperature"]
0: "plant"
1: "water"
2: "time"
length: 3
```

I then call this function to be able to use the data from the API in my datatables javascript:

```
import { getAuth, getDomain } from "./yaml.js";

export function populateTable() {

    var token = getAuth();
    
    var table_data = getDomain(token); // this gets the JSON data

    var ieColumns = [{
        title: "Name",
        type: "text"
    }];

     var E = $('#Forestry').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        data: table_data,
        columns: ieColumns,
        dom: 'frtBip',        // Needs button container
        select: 'single',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add'        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Edit',
                name: 'edit'        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Delete',
                name: 'delete'      // do not change name
            }
        ], style: "width:100%"
    });
```

When I try to parse the JSON data using the parse function, I get an error from datatables complaining it is not in valid format.

I have also wrapped the function call getting the data from the API in brackets like this

```
var table_data = [getDomain(token)]; // this gets the JSON data
```

This returns one row with the first element in the JSON object which is plant but not the others.
The object type this returns is an array(3).

I want it to return each element in a separate row.

Comment: Log table_data to the console and see the output.

Comment: DataTables expects your JSON to be an array of arrays `[ [...], [...], ... ]`, or an array of objects `[ {...}, {...}, ... ]` The outer array represents the entire data set, and each item in the array represents _a row of data_. You are only providing a plain array `[ ... ]`. You therefore need to adjust the structure of your JSON. I would expect to see this: `{ "data": [ ["plant"], ["water"], ["temperature"] ] }` - which is an array of arrays, where the outer array has the name `data` (which is the default name expected by DataTables).

Comment: A more detailed overview is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945645/12567365).