# Using datatables when returning json objects

Tags: json, ajax, datatables

I want to use datatable to return JSON from txt or some web api.
So, everything works well if data is in following format (coopInformation.txt):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "employer": "Unisys",
            "degree": "NETSYS-MS",
            "city": "Blue Bell PA",
            "term": "20151"
        },
        {
            "employer": "Paychex Inc",
            "degree": "INFOST-MS",
            "city": "Rochester NY",
            "term": "20151"
        },
        {
            "employer": "Paychex Inc",
            "degree": "INFOST-MS",
            "city": "Rochester NY",
            "term": "20151"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my jquery call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: 'ajax/data/coopInformation.txt',
        
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'employer'
            },
            {
                data: 'degree'
            },           
            {
                data: "city"
            },
            {
                data: "term"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

But when json object don't start with "data", for example starts with "coopInformation", this call returns an error even if I change columns to coopInformation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: 'ajax/data/coopInformation.txt',
        
        columns: [
            {
                coopInformation: 'employer'
            },
            {
                coopInformation: 'degree'
            },           
            {
                coopInformation: "city"
            },
            {
                coopInformation: "term"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at jquery.dataTables.min.js:65
> at h (jquery.dataTables.min.js:51)
> at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:52)
> at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
> at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
> at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)

It looks like this libs are predefined to use "data" or I am wrong...
My question is: how to make a simple call like this using something else but not "data". On datatables web, all examples are used with this "data".

Kind regards,
Milan

Comment: By default DataTables expects your JSON array to be named `"data"` - like in your first JSON example: `{ "data": [ ... ] }`. If your JSON has a different structure, you need to use the `dataSrc` option to tell DataTables where your array is located in your JSON. For example if the array does not have a name (your 2nd example) then you use `dataSrc: ""`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945645/12567365) for more details and examples.

Comment: Note that you **do** need to use `data: 'employer'` in your column definitions, regardless of the structure of your JSON - as opposed to something like `coopInformation: 'employer'`, which will never be valid. Here `data` is a keyword, like `title`, `name` and others. These are all pre-defined by DataTables to represent different types of column-related information.