# Getting a Jquery DataTable Error (Unknown Parameter)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I'm getting the following error. I know there are similar answered questions but I have tried to use those answers but I am still unable to see my error.

Error Message:

[image]

I have the correct amount of columns in the table and in the request. I have checked for typo's. I am using a video as a guide and I have done everything exactly the same, yet mine doesn't work
code:

```
    <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Address1</th>
            <th>Address2</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Account1</th>
            <th>Account2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section mydataTable{
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable(
            {
                "processing": true,
                "filter": false,
                "serverSide": true,
                "paging": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "ajax":
                {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("LoadData")",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                },
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "defaultContent": "-", "targets": "_all" },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 0, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 2, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 3, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 4, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 5, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 6, "orderable": false },
                    { "width": "auto", "targets": 7, "orderable": false },

                ],
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Title", "name": "CTitle" },
                    { "data": "FirstName", "name": "CFirstName" },
                    { "data": "Surname", "name": "CSurname" },
                    { "data": "Address1", "name": "CAddress1" },
                    { "data": "Address2", "name": "CAddress2" },
                    { "data": "Town", "name": "CTown" },
                    { "data": "Account1", "name": "CAccount1" },
                    { "data": "Account2", "name": "CAccount2" },
                ],

            });
    });
</script>
```

}

C#:

```
    public JsonResult LoadData()
    {
        IEnumerable<DeathClaims> deathclaims = GetDc();
        return Json(new { data = deathclaims, recordsFiltered = deathclaims.Count(), recordsTotal = deathclaims.Count() });
    }

    private IEnumerable<DeathClaims> GetDc()
    {
        List<DeathClaims> deathlist = new List<DeathClaims>()
        {
            new DeathClaims {
                            Title = "Mr",
                            FirstName = "Michael",
                            Surname = "Smith",
                            Address1 = "132 Spalding Road",
                            Address2 = "TS252JP",
                            Town = "Hartlepool",
                            Account1 = "Current Account 1.0%",
                            Account2 = "Super Saver 3.0%"},
            new DeathClaims {
                            Title = "Mr",
                            FirstName = "Steve",
                            Surname = "Smith",
                            Address1 = "1 Something Close",
                            Address2 = "TS273QQ",
                            Town = "Hartlepool",
                            Account1 = "Current Account 1.0%",
                            Account2 = "Super Saver 2.0%"}
        };
        return deathlist;
    }
```

None of the data is getting through - I'm sure it's a small issue but I just cant see it
Thank you in advance for your help

Thanks

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside LoadData, does it hit the method? Try taking the datatable initialization outside of document ready inside your script tag.

Comment: What is the overall structure of the JSON sent to your DataTable? If it's something like `{ "deathlist": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ] }`, then your DataTables `ajax` section needs to use the `dataSrc` option: `"dataSrc": "deathlist"`. For more background, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945645/12567365).

Answer (score 0):

For DataTables plugin to work at server-side. You need to return the JSON in LoadData() method as follow i.e.

```
...

// Initialization.
string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];  
string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];  
string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];  
string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];  
int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);  
int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);  

...

// Process your code.

...

JsonResult result = this.Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = recFilter, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  

return result;
    
...
```

The above properties of DataTables plugin are needed to be captured and maintained in your code by yourself.