# Data tables not responding to provided json result from api call to fill table with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This is the JSON result being return from the API call.

```
{
"LoanOfficers": [{
    "Id": 13,
    "FirstName": "Smith",
    "LastName": "Kerry",
    "EmailAddress": "kerry.smith@test.com",
    "LoanOfficerUrlParameterId": 312,
    "UrlParameter": "/smithkerry123"
}, {
    "Id": 713,
    "FirstName": "Kerry",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "EmailAddress": "kerry.smith@test.com",
    "LoanOfficerUrlParameterId": 654,
    "UrlParameter": "/kerrysmith1234578"
 }]
}
```

I implemented the data table below. The call works and fetches the data and puts it into an object. From there the table reads no data in the table. I use a console.log() to see if the data was being passed back but it is but I don't know why it's not returning to the datable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/CallAPI',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                assignToEventsColumns(data);
            }
        });

        function assignToEventsColumns(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var table = $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "aaData": data,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "FirstName" },
                    { "data": "LastName" },
                    { "data": "EmailAddress" },
                    { "data": "LoanOfficerUrlParameterId" },
                    { "data": "UrlParameter" }
                ],
                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            })


        }
    });
```

[Console log of the JSON object return from API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRJ7I.jpg)

I am new to data tables with JSON data don't understand fully understand why this issue is occurring. Any explanation would be much appreciated. All is I know that is returning a valid JSON format because I already tested that. I provided as much detail as possible. I provided an example of the JSON result and an example of console.log.

HTML

```
 <table class="dataTable table table-striped text-center table-hover" id="table_id">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-green">
                                    <th>Loan Officer ID</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Email Address</th>
                                    <th>LoanOfficerUrlParameterId</th>
                                    <th>Url</th>
                                    @*<th></th>*@
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr class="bg-green">
                                    <th>Loan Officer ID</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Email Address</th>
                                    <th>LoanOfficerUrlParameterId</th>
                                    <th>Url</th>
                                    @*<th></th>*@
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>

                        </table>
```

Comment: Try changing `"aaData": data` to `"aaData": data.LoanOfficers`. This is because the JSON `[ ... ]` array where your row data is located is `data.LoanOfficers`, not `data`.

Comment: You could potentially simplify your code by using DataTables' [built-in support](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) for ajax. You may also want to update your option names from the older naming convention to the new one - so, for example, change `aaData` to `data` - see [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks. It worked.  I see know what you are referring to! Will look into the documentation more also thanks.

Comment: For more background on this, see here: [When using Ajax with jQuery DataTables, how do I determine what to do with the data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944852/when-using-ajax-with-jquery-datatables-how-do-i-determine-what-to-do-with-the-d/64945645#64945645)