# Can't feed datatable ajax with controller response data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller, datatable

[Datatable doesn't load data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYwv0.png)
from controller response

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/devicetype/all",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

[Controller response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0XF0.png)

Already tried to serialize data before returning it, but nothing changed.

Comment: create a fiddle.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944852/when-using-ajax-with-jquery-datatables-how-do-i-determine-what-to-do-with-the-d/64945645#64945645) for more background on handling different JSON structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables expects JSON to be wrapped inside a **data:** object by default, however, you can set the **dataSrc** property to an empty string in order to use a custom flat array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/devicetype/all",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer just literally killed my problem, thank you :')