# How to load json data to datatables ( data which was converted from array to Json )?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

I am converting a javascript array into json and afterwards trying to load it to the datatable but the data is not showing in the tabel

**Here I am reading the csv file and loading the data into an array:**

```
$.ajax({ url: "Users.csv",  async: false, success: function (csvd) { data1 = $.csv.toArrays(csvd); },
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function () { } });
```

**Here is how I am converting the array into json :**

```
var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, data1)); 
var stringToJsonObject =  JSON.parse (arrayToString) ;  
console.log(stringToJsonObject);
```

**and here I am trying to load the json data into the tables:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { var table = $('#example').DataTable({ "data": stringToJsonObject, select:"single",
         "columns": [ { "className": 'details-control', "orderable": false,  "data": null,  "defaultContent": '',
                 "render": function () {  return '<i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>'; },  width:"15px" },
               { "data": "0" },
               { "data": "1" },
               { "data": "2" },
               { "data": "3" },
               { "data": "4" }
         ], "order": [[1, 'asc']] });
```

**but its not working , so I tried loading a static json data into the datatable like this :**

```
 var testdata = {"data": [{"0": "Tiger","1": "tech","2": "$320,800","3": "2011/04/25","4": "Edinburgh","5": "5421"}]};
```

and it works perfectly , but the data that is converted from array to json is not working so I logged both `var testdata` and `var stringToJsonObject` into the console and I noticed that the structure of converted data is different from the structure of static data

**This is the output of `var stringToJsonObject` in console:**

```
{0: Array(6)} 
    0:(6) ["Tiger Nixon ","System Architect", "$320,800", "2011/04/25", "Edinburgh", "5421"]
    length: 6
```

**and this is the output of `var testdata` :**

```
{data: Array(3)}
     data: Array(3)
         0: {0: "Tiger Nixon", 1: "System Architect", 2: "$320,800", 3: "2011/04/25", 4: "Edinburgh", 5: "5421"}
         length: 1
```

**I am assuming the issue it due to `length: 6` or `Array(6)` ?
How can I load the converted data into the datatable ?**

Comment: Update your post with the raw data of Users.csv

Comment: You need to use the `dataSrc` option - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944852/when-using-ajax-with-jquery-datatables-how-do-i-determine-what-to-do-with-the-d/64945645#64945645) for a walk-through. Your hard-coded test data works because it is contained in a _named_ array - and that name is `"data"` - `var testdata = {"data": [{"0": "Tiger"...`. But your actual data does not contain a _named_ array - therefore the `dataSrc` option needs to reflect that: `"dataSrc": ""`.

Comment: Suggestion: It would be easier to help if you provided the actual JSON text (formatted appropriately in the question) rather than providing copy/pastes of the JavaScript objects from the console. It is the JSON data that we need to see, in this specific case. So, if my suggestion above did not help, then definitely show us the JSON.