# Show json value in jquery ajax datatables result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I add `json` data in database like this (in database column social):

```
{"twitter":"test","instagram":"test1","linkedin":"test2"}
```

for show `result` in `datatables`:

```
var tableUser = $('#table-user').DataTable({
    dom: 'rt<"card-footer"<"row" <"col-md-6"i> <"col-md-6"p>>>',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    order: [
        [1, 'asc']
    ],

    ajax: {
        url: '<?= route_to('admin/user/manage') ?>',
        method: 'GET'
    },
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        targets: [0, 4, 5]
    }],
    columns: [
        {
            'data': function(data) {
                return data.social 
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

Result is(`return data.social`):

```
{"twitter":"test","instagram":"test1","linkedin":"test2"}
```

In action I need to specific value like: `twitter` or `instagram`. How to show this result?!

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax), in particular the section "Column data points > 2) Object of data"

Comment: Some notes: (1) DataTables expects to receive an array of arrays, or an array of objects. Your JSON is neither of these. (2) In your `ajax` section you can use the `dataSrc` option to specify the name of the array. (3) Your `columns` definition does not need to use a function if you fix (1) and (2).

Comment: Some background notes: [When using Ajax with jQuery DataTables, how do I determine what to do with the data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944852/when-using-ajax-with-jquery-datatables-how-do-i-determine-what-to-do-with-the-d/64945645#64945645). You can edit your question to show your updated attempt, if you are still facing issues.