# PHP Encoding sqlite query results as JSON and bind to JQUERY Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Using PHP v8.1.6 and SQLITE 3.39.4 and jQuery Datatable.  The json I get back from the php script isn't binding to the table.

The script that fetches the data:

```
 $db = new SQLite3('mealplan.db');
     $results = $db->query('SELECT id, [name] FROM mealType;');
     while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
         $jsonArray[] = $row;
     }
     echo json_encode($jsonArray)
```

The javascript that sets up the datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#tbl').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:'processing.php',
        columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "name" }
        ]
    });  
});
```

In the network tab, here is the raw json i get back from the php script:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Snack"},{"id":2,"name":"Dinner"},{"id":3,"name":"Lunch"},{"id":4,"name":"Breakfast"},{"id":5,"name":"Sweets"},{"id":6,"name":"Drinks"}]
```

The datatable gets rendered with all the datable features, it's just empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you need to add a header `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` to the PHP script.

Comment: @TelmoDias thank you for the reply.  On your advice, I added that declaration to the php file. Unfortunately it did not change anything.

Comment: By default, DataTables expects the JSON response array to be contained in an object called `data` - so: `{ "data": [ ... ] }`. Your JSON response (as shown in the question) is just a raw array. Therefore, try re-writing your DataTables `ajax` option to include `"dataSrc: ""`.  For more discussion and examples, see [When using Ajax with jQuery DataTables, how do I determine what to do with the data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945645/12567365)

Comment: @andrewJames.  I added the dataSrc:"" to the ajax option.  No change, unfortunately.  It seems that my JSON is coming back from the PHP script as an array of objects, [{...}, {...}, {...}] but the datatable wants an array of arrays [ [...], [...], [...] ].  I'm not sure how the write the php to return the array of arrays.

Comment: Datatables wants an array of arrays or an array of objects. Both work. See the discussion in the link. Also show us how you added your `dataSrc` option.

Comment: Also, given you are using server-side = true, you need to return the JSON for that mode. But to start with, get it working with server-side = false. It is much more straightforward. Then change to server-side = true, afterwards.

Comment: @andrewJames thanks for your help.  I resolved by CORRECTLY adding the dataSrc property INSIDE the ajax value.  I edited my post to show the working code.

Comment: Please put the solution into an answer. Don't add it to the question. (But, really, this question is a duplicate, and should be closed as such). Glad you solved it, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solution.
My issue was not having the dataSrc attribute INSIDE the ajax property.  Here is the working javascript:

```
 $('#tbl').DataTable({
        ajax:{url:'processing.php',dataSrc:""},
        columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "name" },
        ]           
    });
```