# How can I populate DataTable with JSON and insert multiselect filters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

I am very new to coding and DataTables. I have an example here (sourced from the DataTable forums) of exactly what I need to do with my DataTable: http://live.datatables.net/xehexoye/1463/edit.

However, instead of populating my table with plain HTML as in the example, I need to populate my table with a local JSON file from my repo (example URL: ./data/myJSON.json) and then implement the multi-select filters from the example linked above.

I was able to pull in my JSON data and get my arrays to show up in the console like this:

```
var tableData = []

$ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   URL: './data/myJSON.json',
   success:function(response){
       tableData = staff
console.log(tableData)
    }
})
```

and my JSON file looks similar to this setup (in case this is needed):

```
[{
"staff": {
"Name": "Jane Doe",
"Birthday": "1999-07-09",
"Email": "janedoe@gmail.com"
   }
},
{
"staff": {
"Name": "John Doe",
"Birthday": "1958-03-18",
"Email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
   }
}]
```

I believe the most efficient way without having to modify the JS in the example too much would be to make a template HTML string from this JSON data and insert the ID from this template string into the DataTable initialization but am unsure how to do so. Any guidance on this to help push me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: First, you have to use `JSON.parse()` to convert your JSON into a normal Array of objects. Then simply use a `for`-loop to generate your HTML markup with `insertAdjacentHTML`

Comment: You should use the built-in [DataTables Ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) instead of JQuery, then look at the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to generate your HTML.

Comment: Hi @tacoshy! Thanks so much for such a speedy reply to my question. I am stuck on how to structure my code for all this which is what I need the most help with. Do you have an applied code example you might be able to share with me so I can understand how to write a statement like you described? Thanks so much again for your help.

Comment: Use DataTables' built-in support for Ajax, as @mark_b already says. You _can_ use jQuery outside of DataTables, but unless you have a more complex use-case, there typically no need to do this. And it typically requires more work than you need to do. The only thing that may catch you out is how to tell DataTables where your JSON array `[ ... ]` is located in your data. Use the [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option for this. If you have a plain array, use `"dataSrc": ""`. If your JSON data array is inside an object `{ ... }`, use the object's name.

Comment: Related: [When using Ajax with jQuery DataTables, how do I determine what to do with the data returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64945645/12567365)

Comment: @andrewJames every time I try to use the Ajax, such as this:

`$(document).ready(function () {
$(#example).DataTable({
ajax: './data/myJSON.json',
dataSrc: "staff",
...})
})`
I get a console error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')** in my console and my table does not populate.

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax for `dataSrc` - you have to re-structure your `ajax` option so that `dataSrc` (and also the URL) is inside it.  See the examples in the `dataSrc` documentation (already linked above). Take a closer look at the answer I also linked to, because that will explain what value you need to use for `dataSrc: "???"`. It's probably not `"staff"`... Based on the JSON in your question it's `"dataSrc": ""`, as I noted above.

Comment: @andrewJames thank you for that clarification! My table has populated with my JSON file but the filter dropdowns (from the example datatables code I linked in my original question) are now missing. I have no console errors at the moment though. Is there something I need to modify in the code handling the dropdowns now that I am calling in my data directly from the JSON rather than calling in the plain HTML as the author of the code does?

Comment: You should probably add a new **Update** section to the end of your question, so that you can show your new code, and describe the new problem. You can [edit] the question to do that. Try to provide a [mre] so the community can recreate your problem.

Comment: I actually got it figured out yesterday evening! Linking to my JSON via ajax and defining my columns worked, I was missing my table footer in the HTML. Once I added that the table populated with my filters. Thanks so much for everybody taking the time to help out. I appreciate it!