# Jquery datatable set up correctly yet reading 'length' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

Jquery datatables seem to be the bane of my existence. Something always goes wrong. I want to fully learn why it goes wrong and the generic error doesn't help me.

So I've set up a table like so:

```
<table id="NameList">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tfoot>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
```

and the JS code like this:

```
    var table = $('#NameList').DataTable({
     "ajax": '...php',
     "processing": true,
     "columns": [
         {"data": "ID"},
         {"data": "PeopleNames"}       
     ],
     "order": [[0, 'desc']],
     "pageLength": 50
    });
```

and the JSON data comes back as correct, throws up no errors. Yet, whenever I do anything I get the error back of *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')*. WHY? What's missing? I have read the documentation several times and everything checks out for me. Is there something broken in Jquery or have I just missed something simple?

EDIT: As requested, here is JSON. Browser doesn't throw an error unlike the times when I do have JSON wrong. Since there's no popups I assume all is working.

```
 [
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "PeopleNames": "Test1"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "PeopleNames": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "PeopleNames": "Test3"
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "PeopleNames": "Test4"
  },
  {
    "ID": "5",
    "PeopleNames": "Test5"
  },
  {
    "ID": "6",
    "PeopleNames": "Test6"
  },
  {
    "ID": "7",
    "PeopleNames": "Test7"
  },
  {
    "ID": "8",
    "PeopleNames": "Test8"
  }
]
```

Comment: Show us your JSON - add it to the question as formatted text. If the JSON is large, you can show a representative sample - but make sure you show us the correct structure.

Comment: In case it may help (but it may not help at all), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64944852/12567365) which discusses the different JSON structures you may need to handle.

Comment: I added JSON as you requested. Looks alright to me, hopefully I know basics.

Comment: Suggest you not do your request like `"ajax": '...php',` but more like `ajax: '...php',`

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Yes, that is valid JSON, but it is in an _unnamed_ array `[ {...},{...},... ]` - which is what I discuss in that linked question in my previous comment. So, at the very least you need to change your `"ajax": '...php'` option accordingly. That is a necessary change - but it may not be sufficient to solve all the problems in the DataTable.

Comment: So, something like this: `ajax: { url: '...php', dataSrc: '' },`. Note the `ajax` option now has nested attributes, to allow you to use the `dataSrc: ''` option for your unnamed JSON array. (You don't need to use `"ajax":` with more recent versions of DataTables - you can just use `ajax:` - but `"ajax":` is still valid.)

Comment: Well my ajax has got an actual address, it's not empty. Just don't wanna doxx myself with all the file structures. Not sure if that's how it works tho

Comment: "_my ajax has got an actual address_" - OK - understood, but that is not the point I am trying to make (if your comment was for me). I am referring to your JSON structure. Not to the URL.

Comment: Please explain how does my json is unnamed? Haven't I already got 2 named fields when you open up the json array position? Those being "ID" and "PeopleNames?"

Comment: I didn't say your JSON is unnamed. I said your JSON array is unnamed. The array is this: `[ {...},{...},... ]`. It is *not* this: `{ "my_data": [ {...},{...},... ] }`. It is not inside an object. See the link in my second comment, where this is explained - why it is important, and why you will not be able to load your data if you do not take this into account.